# Need to test string for instance of words from list in F#

Tags: f#, comparison, match

I have a list of words in F# and a string input. I want to see if any of the words in the list are contained in the string. If I was using C# Id run a foreach loop on each word in the string.split and run an List.contains comparison. I have come up with the following code so far, but can't seem to access List.contains on the value 'str'

```
 let checkforvalue(x:string) = 
  for str in x.Split(' ') do
    match str with commandList -> Console.WriteLine(str + " found: " + x)
  ()
```

The current function always returns true and executes the Console.WriteLine method.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the semantics of the [pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) syntax. The `match str with commandList` will not go through the `commandList` and see if `str` 'matches' any of the strings in `commandList`.

Instead, it will try to destructure `str` into a pattern that you provide, which in your case says nothing about the actual structure, so anything will effectively be matched and bound to the name `commandList`.

As @JohnPalmer pointed out, this will just shadow your other `commandList` binding. But anyway, I don't think pattern matching is a proper way to solve your problem, even (especially?) if you go as far as using [Active Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx).

Here's how you could solve this problem instead:

```
let checkForValue (str : string) commandList =
    // convert to set for better performance
    let commands = Set.ofList commandList
    str.Split(' ') |> Seq.exists (fun x -> Set.contains x commands)
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. I'm coming from an OO background and F# has been so much more than just learning a new syntax.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you're essentially doing set intersection, which can be expressed more simply:

```ml
Set.intersect (set (x.Split(' '))) (set commandList)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `commandList` when used how you have used it creates a new variable which shadows the old.

You probably want something like

```
let checkforvalue(x:string) = 
  for str in x.Split(' ') do
    match str with s when s=commandList -> Console.WriteLine(str + " found: " + x)
```

if `commandList` is a string

If it is a list you could do:

```
let checkforvalue(x:string) = 
  for str in x.Split(' ') do
    if List.exists (fun s -> s=str) commandlist then Console.WriteLine(str + " found: " + x)
```